# Duda de optimizacion de aplicacion

Tags: c#

Hice un proceso en c# el cual se esta ejecutando todo el tiempo, el problemas es usa mucho porcentaje de CPU, alguien sabe como reducir ese porcentaje?

```
do
            {
                try
                {

                    LogClasifica("Configurando Directorios...");  
                    lector.obtenFiles(fields);
         }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Message);
                }
            }
            while (true);




    public void obtenFiles(string[] field)
    {
        try
        {

            List<string> dirsRaiz = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(field[1]));

            foreach (var dir in dirsRaiz)
            {

                if (dir.Contains(field[21]) || dir.Contains(field[22]) || dir.Contains(field[23]))
                {

                    String dirPath2 = dir;
                    List<string> dirs2 = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath2));

                    foreach (string dir2 in dirs2)
                    {

                        if (dir2.Contains("AUX"))
                        {
                            //LogClasifica(dir2);
                            int subString2 = Convert.ToInt16(field[45]);
                            string string3 = dir2.Substring(subString2);
                            n = Convert.ToInt16(string3);
                            if (n >= Convert.ToInt16(field[37]) && n <= Convert.ToInt16(field[38])) //CONDICION PARA USESAP
                            {
                                if (dir.Contains(field[21]))
                                {
                                    if (!Directory.Exists(field[10]))
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(field[10]);
                                    }

                                    CopyDirectoryContent2(dir2.Substring(0, subString2) + n, field[10], true);
                                }
                                if (dir.Contains(field[22]) || dir.Contains(field[23]))
                                {
                                    if (!Directory.Exists(field[11]))
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(field[11]);
                                    }
                                    CopyDirectoryContent2(dir2.Substring(0, subString2) + n, field[11], true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }    
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            LogClasifica("Error:" + err.Message + err.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Es cada un cierto tiempo? o es un bucle que lo ejecuta?

Comment: y seria bueno que pongas el código del proceso.

Comment: Es un bucle  que lee archivos todo el tiempo
do
            {
                try
                {

                    LogClasifica("Configurando Directorios...");  
                    lector.obtenFiles(fields);
   }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Message);
                }
            }
            while (true);

Comment: creo que deberias explicarte con algo mas de detalle, que funcionalidad realiza la aplicacion, se conecta a alguna db ? procesa algun archivo? cuanto es el intervalo del tiempo

Comment: pero procesa archivos que caen a una carpeta? si es asi porque no usas el FileSystemWatcher

Comment: Utiliza un profiler para tu aplicación. Esta herramienta te brindará información del rendimiento, consumo de memoria, manejo de hilos, etc. Asimismo, te indicará cuáles son los cuellos de botella y lugares donde se dan los picos de consumo de memoria de la aplicación.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código ahí. el código que pusiste en el comentario y el de la función lector.obtenFiles(fields)

Comment: que funcionalidad implementa el lector.obtenFiles() es quein determina cuando aparece un archivo nuevo en la carpeta?

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, podrias decirme como utilizar un profiler o una liga de información, por favor

Comment: Leandro Tuttini, ya coloque la funcion de obtebFiles(). Saludos

Comment: Comentarios, comentarios, comentarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas, sobre todo de construcción de código.

Para el tema del performance una solución como la de @leandro te vendría bien, y o iba a proponerte esta

```
const int WAIT = 1000;//1 seg, pero puede ser menos o mucho menos segun lo que requieras

do
{
   logClasifica("Configurando Directorios...");
   lector.obtenFiles(fields);
   Thread.Sleep(WAIT);
}
while (true);
```

Con esto ganas varias mejoras

1. le das un respiro a la IO en especial por las escrituras en disco, tener un wait loop que escribe en disco sin parar es una **pésima ** idea
2. **no hagas un control de excepciones** tan grande, mejor maneja excepciones donde sea pertinente en los otros métodos. un manejo de excepciones de la forma que lo tienes es DEMASIADO costoso.

**Pero..**

Tu código esta muy desordenado, te recomendaría encapsular la lógica en un método o clase diferente. Por lo general un método tan largo como el que tienes es una señal de que tiene demasiadas responsabilidades, lo que implica que no tienes muy bien modelada tu solución.

Un clase : una responsabilidad, un método una responsabilidad...  fragmenta, agrupa y ordena funcionalidades.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que veo poco por optimizar.

La parte del proceso de los directorios en el metodo `obtenFiles()` es muy particular a la logica que necesitas, no sabria decirte como cambiar esa parte sin entender de fondo que necesitas realizar.

Si puedo mencionar que no uses un `do..while` para repetir el ciclo, implementa un timer que ejecute cada cierto tiempo.

```
Timer t1 = null;

public void Form1_Load(...){

    t1 = new Timer();
    t1.Interval = 1000;
    t1.Tick += t1_Tick;

    t1.Start();

}

public void t1_Tick(...){

    t1.Stop();

    LogClasifica("Configurando Directorios...");  
    lector.obtenFiles(fields);

    t1.Start();
}
```

Tambien podrias evaluar lanzar el proceso en un `thread` (hilo), para que no bloquee la aplicacion.
Para esto podrias usar el timer que esta en `System.Threading`

[Temporizadores de subprocesos (Visual C# y Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/swx5easy.aspx)